# How to stop backgrounddownload exe

Tags: windows-10, visual-studio-2019, background-process

As per attached screen shot BackgroundDownload.exe is running in background and consuming lots of internet data. How it can be stopped?
[image]

Comment: I have the amusing, related, issue that my firewall automatically blocks this when I want to allow it. It's difficult to allow an exception because of the random path name and IP address.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Please check if its checked “Automatically download updates” in VS2019?

Uncheck it.

Tools->Options->Environment->Product Updates->Automatically download updates

[image]

Comment: It solved me for a while, but maybe a newer version still checks for updates (but doesn't download them) and therefore my firewall sends the warnings.

Comment: this solution doesn't work as of May, 2021

Comment: This solution does not work. You can uncheck the box, but Visual Studio now ignores the setting and the huge background downloads still happen.

Answer (score 70):

This however does not stop VS from recreating BackgoundDownload.exe in 'random' temp directories and trying again. There must be some other missed option. Perhaps disabling the scheduled task in 'task scheduler' would finalize the change.

Through control panel, or other means,
open 'Task Scheduler'. in the navigation pane on the left side, navigate to

*"Task Scheduler Library>Microsoft>VisualStudio>Updates"*

when there, you will see a task named *'BackroundDownload'*

Right click on this task and either disable, or delete it.

Comment: The tigger is "on idle", that explains why my cpu fan rotating frantically every time my computer on idle, and backgrounddownload.exe would disappear when I try to find the consuming process —— it's suck.

Comment: This is an important addition to the solution as the selected one (disable Automatic Download Updates) only seems to apply while Visual Studio is running. This separate Task Scheduler event runs whenever the computer is idle regardless. In my experience, "idle" means no interaction from mouse/keyboard for only a few seconds, so it triggers quite often.  Note that even this will not entirely stop it, but it helps.

Answer (score 9):

The same update process initiated by from Visual Studio Code. You can disable it via settings menu (and do not forget to uncheck sending telemetry)
[image: The same update process initiated by from Visual Studio Code]

Answer (score 7):

It's possible to turn background downloading off for **all installed Visual Studio products** by creating/changing a `DWORD` registry key:

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Setup\BackgroundDownloadDisabled = 1`

Source: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/visual-studio-background-downloader-keeps-running/948890#T-N950950

Answer (score 1):

there is another way

Open Windows Defender Firewall With Advanced Security from the search next to Start

[image]
Then click on (( Outbound Rules -> New Rules ))

[image]
Now a new page will open, click ( Program ), then click (Next)

Now click on (This Program Path)
And enter this URL :
(%ProgramFiles% (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\ServiceHub\Services\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Service\BackgroundDownload.exe)

[image]

Now click Next again and select Block The Connection on this page and click Next again

[image]

Do not touch anything on this page (Profile) and click on Next

Finally, select a name in the (Name) field and write a series of descriptions if needed

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please go to your connectivity setting I mean I am using my hotspot from mobile.
go to your wifi icon on windows 10.

then select properties and it will take you to another screen.

there is toggle switch called metered connection. select it .
That's it if wants to download also it cannot.
As a default windows does not allow you to download any updates in background.
You can do it when you are want. [image: step 1]  .[Step 2][2]